# Can't get to requested URL of a web page that requires a login using requests in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm new to web scraping and I just couldn't find the solution to my problem.
I'm stuck at the login page.

```
import requests

POST_LOGIN_URL = 'https://ocjene.skole.hr/pocetna/prijava'  # Login page
REQUEST_URL = 'https://ocjene.skole.hr/pregled/predmeti'  # Goal page for scraping

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get(POST_LOGIN_URL)  # Loading all cookies...
    login_page = session.get(POST_LOGIN_URL)  # Login page content (for comparison)
    token = session.cookies["csrf_cookie"]  # This cookie on chrome has a valid csrf token

    payload = {
        'csrf_token': token,
        'user_login': 'xxx',
        'user_password': 'xxx'
    }
    post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload)  # Logging in...

    afterLogin = session.get(REQUEST_URL)  # This is where I need to get all the content, but...

print(subject_math.content)
print(login_page.content)
# These two share exact same content, except the csrf token is different
```

I'm not sure if logging in was successful. I double-checked everything,
the form data is correct and I also tried replacing the request headers like so:

```
post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

What am I missing? thanks.

Comment: Just remember that when you access a link from `requests`, it doesn't load Chrome's cookies like this, as the only thing you're doing with the beginning of your code, is trying to load a `post login` page that won't open, as you haven't done the login. 
For working with cookies, you could use any lib to get Chrome cookies before using them, or using another method. 
For scrapping content from pages who require login, I personally prefer to use Selenium, as it's easier to login and save Chrome's profile:
https://www.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like chrome is posting to `posalji/`

Also inspect `post.content` after the request, that should tell you if it was ok.

Comment: The post.content is the log-in page, which means I failed to log in... Is it because chrome is posting to this name: 'posalji/', and my session.post is only looking for 'login' name? What should I do now and how can I change the name session.post is looking for?

Comment: The url that has the login form is not the same url that you want to post to. Just post to the same url as chrome.